# How to respond to paypal payment

Tags: node.js, express, paypal, server

**Some context:** I am developing a website with NodeJS and the Express framework. There is one section of the site where users can take the color personality test. When they're done the test, all their answers (including name, email, and other contact info) gets sent to the server through POST. The user gets redirected to a page where they can choose to pay for an evaluation of their profile with a Paypal button.

**My question:** how do I retrieve the information from the original test form after the IPN listener gets triggered? Should I store the user's info in a database? If I do that, I'm not sure how I would retrieve the correct user's info after the payment notification.

**The process should look something like this:** Users Takes Test > Results sent to server > Server redirects user to the payment page > User pays > IPN gets triggered > Do something with test results (like send an email or something).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your payment request you can include a record ID in the "invoice" parameter, assuming you're using PayPal Standard HTML code.  So it would look like this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="invoice" value="1234" />
```

Of course you would replace 1234 with the value of your record ID that you save in your database.

That value will come back as `$_POST['invoice']` within the IPN data, so you can pull the data back out of your database.

You could do the same thing using the "custom" parameter if you'd rather use that instead of "invoice".

```
<input type="hidden" name="custom" value="1234" />
```

Then `$_POST['custom']` would come back in IPN.

Comment: Thanks! I might even just use JSON.stringify so I can send the info through without a db.

Comment: That would work with the custom parameter.  Keep in mind it's limited to 256 characters.